# Quarkus is unable to serialize a simple string as JSON

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, quarkus

My Quarkus app has a single class, which is the following:

```java
package org.acme;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello from Quarkus REST";
    }
}
```

The expected response would be:

```http
200 OK HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

"Hello from Quarkus REST"
```

Instead, it returns:

```http
200 OK HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

Hello from Quarkus REST
```

The JSON cannot be parsed since it is not valid because of the missing quotes.

Any idea why Jackson is not serializing my `String` as JSON ?

It seems weird because the `Content-Type` header is still indicating that the response is a JSON.

I can't find anything documenting this behavior on Quarkus website.

Comment: "Hello from Quarkus REST" is not a valid json , it is an application text plain (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) , you should return for json something like this {"message": "Hello from Quarkus REST"}

Comment: A Java object is never a valid JSON. The purpose of Jackson is to serialize them as JSON. I don't understand what you mean.

And a JSON can be a simple string. It does not necessarily needs to be a JSON object with braces. It is exactly what i want to avoid.

Comment: I don't understand why my question is downvoted. Angry Java devs maybe ?

Yes, simple JSON strings are a thing. Just try to do JSON.stringify on a JS string and you will see that the resulting JSON will have double quotes around it (also it will escape the content inside).